# Apache version 2+ doubles the TimeOut directive on requests

Tags: apache-2.2

We have been testing Apache 2+ versions and on all requests the TimeOut directive set is processed 2 times for a request. You can see the log below (TimeOut set to 2 seconds):

```
[Wed Feb 12 18:04:20 2014] [warn] [client 192.168.19.117] Timeout waiting for output from CGI script /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5
[Wed Feb 12 18:04:20 2014] [error] [client 192.168.19.117] Script timed out before returning headers: php5
[Wed Feb 12 18:04:22 2014] [warn] [client 192.168.19.117] Timeout waiting for output from CGI script /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5
[Wed Feb 12 18:04:22 2014] [error] [client 192.168.19.117] File does not exist: /home/davetest/public_html/504.shtml
```

Apache logs that the request reaches TimeOut set and then allows another 2 seconds interval before returning an error.

The same happens with TimeOut 3 , 5 , 10 etc. - doubles the timeout.

Can you point me to what I am obviously missing here.

EDIT: The php script being executed is simply 60 seconds sleep.

strace output:

http://pastebin.com/h4dHU64X

System Info:

OS: CentOS 6.5

Thanks.

Comment: TimeOut is part of the low level I/O configuration in the Apache core. It's a kind of safety to prevent I/O operations that have blocked from locking the webserver. While I can't really explain the behavior it is not the normal way to control the execution time of PHP scripts. That you usually do with max_execution_time in the php.ini file.

Comment: I cannot but agree, however, I need this specific behaviour understood  .

Answer (score 1):

Apache isn't doing anything wrong: You have two timeouts because you called PHP twice.

The first time was your attempt to load the web page itself, which timed out.

The second time was Apache's attempt to load the [`ErrorDocument`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) which, because it doesn't exist, was passed to PHP for processing.

To resolve the issue, set `ErrorDocument` to a static HTML page that exists.

```
ErrorDocument 504 /failwhale.html
```

Comment: We actually thought of that and we tried adding ErrorDocument as a file, and also just as a message with the following:

ErrorDocument 504 "Gateway Timeout!"

ErrorDocument 504 /504.shtml

Of course, only one directive at a time.

Even when ErrorDocument is defined, Apache still initiates a secondary request and shows the ErrorDocument file/message when the second request times out.

The only difference in the log is that the File Does Not Exist Error no longer appears - as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain this issue myself, and I also want to know why Apache does this "*double Timeout*" since it is quite weird and controversial to the actual Apache documentation.

When using CGI wrapper for PHP I came up with the following "*side*" solution:

```
timeout 30 /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

instead of using:

```
exec /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

This way the execution is killed directly by the kernel when the timeout is reached.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this bug exists in Apache 2.4.41, too. My configuration is [mod_cgid](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cgid.html) (execution of CGI scripts using an external CGI daemon) and [mod_event](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/event.html) (threaded workers for static content).

My timeout is globally set to 300 seconds (5 minutes):

```
Timeout 300
```

Adding the following directive from [mod_cgid](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cgid.html) does not help, and the CGI script continues to work even after the timeout:

```
CGIDScriptTimeout 300
```

Here is the workflow:

```sh
# execution started by the CGI daemon
suexec_log:[2019-11-07 12:43:59]: uid: (4260/vesselin) gid: (3751/vesselin) cmd: timeout2.php

# timeout logged after 5 minutes
error_log:www.example.com [Thu Nov 07 12:48:59 2019] [error] [pid 23226] util_script.c(506): [client 94.155.37.249:59500] Script timed out before returning headers: timeout2.php

# script continues to run; does not get any signal to terminate

# apache sends HTTP error 504 to the browser after *another* 5 minutes
access_log:www.example.com 1.1.1.1 - - [07/Nov/2019:12:43:58 +0200] "GET /timeout2.php HTTP/1.1" 504 417 "-" "curl/7.58.0" 0 0 "off:-:-" 92 600867987 2.2.2.2 www.example.com

# note that the execution time is correctly logged as 600867987 microseconds (600 seconds)
```

This bug has been reported as [Debian Bug #780123](https://lists.debian.org/debian-apache/2015/03/msg00004.html).